# ftp_connect() - resource(2) of type (FTP Buffer)

Tags: php, ftp

```
$connection = ftp_connect("x.x.x.x");
var_dump($connection);
```

OUTPUT:

```
resource(2) of type (FTP Buffer)
```

The same output if changed to `ftp_ssl_connect("x.x.x.x")`

The actual address i am using is 100% correct as i can get shell access

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

This was never resolved.

For anyone else who experiences this issue, the only problem area i could narrow it down to was that some network/ipv4-ipv6 issue outside of my 2 servers.
i was connecting between 2 seperate servers when this issue occurred, but moving the servers onto the same machine resolved the issue

e.g ftp_connect(localhost)